# Data structure with quick min, delete, insert, search for big compute job

Tags: optimization, data-structures, language-agnostic, computer-science, amortized-analysis

I'm looking for a data structure that will let me perform the operations I need efficiently. I expect to traverse a loop between 10<sup>11</sup> and 10<sup>13</sup> times so Ω(*n*) operations are right out. (I'll try to trim *n* down so it can fit in cache but it won't be small.) Each time through the loop I will call

- Min exactly once
- Delete exactly once (delete the minimum, if that helps)
- Insert 0 to 2 times, with an average of somewhat more than 1
- Search once for each insert

I only care about average or amortized performance, not worst-case. (The calculation will take ages, it's no concern if bits of the calculation stall from time to time.) The data will not be adversarial.

What kinds of structures should I consider? Maybe there's some kind of heap modified to have quick search?

Comment: By the way, if you have a resource (cheat sheet, etc.) that I could use to answer this myself, I'd be quite happy to learn about it.

Comment: Would an implementation of a data structure where each one of the operations you described require O(logn) worst case help? Is that what you meant by "Maybe there's some kind of heap modified to have quick search"?

Comment: @Titan3 Absolutely. (I was hoping this was an easy-enough question to not require that level of work, but certainly I'd be happy to take that if it's what you've got.)

Comment: Of interest: [Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/)

Answer (score 1):

A [balanced tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) is a quite good data structure for such a usage. All the specified operations are computed in `O(log n)`. I think you can write an optimized tree implementation so that the minimum can be retrieved in `O(1)` (by keeping an iterator to the min and possibly the value for faster fetches). The resulting time of the algorithm will be `O(m log n)` where `m` is the number of iteration and `n` the number of items in the data structure.

This is the optimal algorithmic complexity. Indeed, assuming each iteration can be done in (amortized) `O(1)`, each of the four operations must have such a complexity too. Let's assume a data structure `S` can be built with such a properties. One can write the following algorithm (written in Python):

```py
def superSort(input):
    s = S()
    inputSize = len(input)
    for i in range(inputSize):
        s.insert(item[i])
    output = list()
    for i in range(inputSize):
        output.append(s.getMin())
        s.deleteMin()
    return output
```

`superSort` has an (amortized) complexity of `O(n)`. However, the theoretical optimal exact algorithmic complexity for a comparison-based sort [has been proven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) to be `O(n log (n))`. Thus, `S` cannot exist and at least one of the 4 operations need to be done in at-least `O(log n)` time.

Note that naive binary tree implementations are often pretty inefficient. There is a lot of optimization you can perform to make them much faster. For example, you can pack the nodes (see [B-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)), put the nodes in an array (assuming the number of item is bounded), use a relaxed balancing possibly based on random properties (see [Treaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap)), use small references (eg. 16-bit indices or 32-bit indices rather than 64-bit pointers), etc. You can start with a naive [AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) or a [splay-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree).

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! I don't think the optimality proof is right -- a backward-sorted array has O(1) min and delete-min, and a trivial O(n) sort from these two (or O(1) by doing nothing, if you're OK with the order being reversed) -- though I also don't expect all four operations can be done in O(1).

Comment: The proof was not very detailed/clear. I improved it. Regarding your example, the backward-sorted array is actually a data structure and it needs to be built first from a set of values. To do that, items need to be sorted unless your input itself is already sorted (which is not specified in the question). Moreover, note that insertion in a sorted array is in `O(n)`. There are some `O(n)` sorts, but none of them are based on comparisons (eg. radix-sort).

Comment: Thank you, this proof is solid (and sharper: it shows that at least one of min, delete-min, and insert must take at least logarithmic time, you don't need the fourth operation).

Answer (score 1):

My suggested data structure requires more work to be implemented, but it does achieve the desired results;
A data structure with `{insert, delete, findMin, search}` operations can be implemented using an AVL tree which ensures that each operation is done in `O(logn)` and `findMin` is done in O(1).

I'm going to dive in a bit into the implementation:

The tree would contain a pointer to the minimum node which is updated on each insertion and deletion, thus `findMin` requires `O(1)`.

`insert` is implemented as it is in every AVL tree which takes `O(logn)` (using the balance factor and rotations/swaps to balance the tree). After you insert an element, you would need to update the minimum node pointer by going all the way to the left from the root of the tree, which requires `O(logn)` as well since the tree height is `O(logn)`.

Likewise, after using `delete` you would need to update the minimum pointer in same fashion, thus it requires `O(logn)`.

Finally, `search` also requires `O(logn)`.

If more assumptions were given, e.g. the inserted elements are within a certain range of the minimum, then you could also give each node in the tree `successor` and `predecessor` pointers, which can also be updated in `O(logn)` during insertions and deletions, and thus can be accessed in `O(1)` without the need to traverse over the entire tree. And searching for the inserted elements can be done faster.

The successor of an inserted node can be updated by going to the right child and then all the way to the left. But if a right child does not exist then you would need to climb up the parents as long as the current node is not the left child of its parent.
The predecessor is updated in the exact reverse way.

In c++ a node would look something like this

```cpp
template <class Key,class Value>
class AvlNode{
private:
    Key key;
    Value value;
    int Height;
    int BF; //balance factor
    AvlNode* Left;
    AvlNode* Right;
    AvlNode* Parent;
    AvlNode* Succ;
    AvlNode* Pred;

public:
...
}
```

While the tree would look something like this:

```cpp
template <class Key,class Value>
class AVL {
private:
    int NumOfKeys;
    int Height;
    AvlNode<Key, Value> *Minimum;
    AvlNode<Key, Value> *Root;

    static void swapLL(AVL<Key, Value> *avl, AvlNode<Key, Value> *root);
    static void swapLR(AVL<Key, Value> *avl, AvlNode<Key, Value> *root);
    static void swapRL(AVL<Key, Value> *avl, AvlNode<Key, Value> *root);
    static void swapRR(AVL<Key, Value> *avl, AvlNode<Key, Value> *root);

public:
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what you told us, I think I would use an open-addressed hash table for search and a heap to keep track of the minimum.

In the heap, instead of storing values, you would store indexes/pointers to the items in the hash table.  That way when you delete min from the heap, you can follow the pointer to find the item you need to delete from the hash table.

The total memory overhead will be 3 or 4 words per item -- about the same as a balanced tree, but the implementation is simpler and faster.